# Launch GstRTSPServer from GstElement pipeline

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I'm doing a Gstreamer 1.0 application in C.
The pipeline is built, based on user configuration and system "state" during runtime.
Therefore I'm using multiple GstElements which are later added and linked to a "GstElement pipeline".
Here's a minimal example for a better understanding:

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("mypipeline");
...
GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", NULL);
...
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, enc, pay, NULL);
gst_element_link_many(src, enc, pay, NULL);
...
```

This pipeline should then be launched by a [GstRTSPMediaFactory](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPMediaFactory.html). The problem I'm facing here is that the [`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPMediaFactory.html#gst-rtsp-media-factory-set-launch) function is only accepting a `const gchar *` pipeline.

Therefore my question is, if anybody of you is aware of a function for either

- transforming the `GstElement *pipeline` to a `const gchar*` representation (kinda reverse [`gst_parse`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch))
- or launching the GstRTSPMediaFactory from a `GstElement *pipeline` (see edit #1 below)

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

---

**EDIT #1:**

From the [gst-rtsp-server documentation](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/89ccaa6932076e634481affef587f2756c577fa8/docs/README):

> The default implementation of GstRTSPMediaFactory allows you to easily create
>    GStreamer pipelines using the gst-launch syntax. It is possible to create a
>    GstRTSPMediaFactory subclass that uses different methods for constructing
>    pipelines.

Therefore launching a GstRTSPMediaFactory from a GstElement is technically possible. Additional question to this approach: Is anybody aware of such an GstRTSPMediaFactory subclass implementation?

Comment: there isnt anything to convert the pipeline to gst-launch string  alternatively you look at [1] for you to implement your option two to pass the pipeline to factory,

[1] http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/RTSP-Server-from-a-manually-created-and-linked-pipeline-td4680305.html

Comment: I would like to do the same. Did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `gst-rtsp-server` repository has [an example](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/-/blob/master/examples/test-onvif-server.c#L523-602) in its subfolder examples. To summarise: make a subclass of `GstRTSPMediaFactory` and override the `create_element()` virtual method.

As an aside, this also means the 2 options you provided before were incorrect;

> - transforming the GstElement *pipeline to a const gchar* representation (kinda reverse gst_parse)

This is not possible, since the programmatic API is more expressive and allows you to do more (even a simple example: registering callbacks) than the declarative launch API.

> - or launching the GstRTSPMediaFactory from a GstElement *pipeline (see edit #1 below)

You're thinking the other way around: when the GStreamer RTSP server gets the request to start playing, it will use the `GstRTSPMediaFactory` to launch a `GstPipeline` based on your `get_element()` implementation. Not the other way around, where each pipeline launches its own RTSP server.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I recently worked on similar problem and its actually very reasonable requirement to build and launch pipeline dynamically based on config.

When creating the source pipeline dynamically, instead of adding `pay` element, use shared memory sink.

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("mypipeline");
...
GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", NULL);
...
GstElement* shmsink = gst_element_factory_make("shmsink", nullptr);
g_object_set(shmsink, "socket-path", "/tmp/stream.socket",
                      "wait-for-connection", false, nullptr);
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, enc, shmsink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many(src, enc, shmsink, NULL);
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

Then construct the second part of pipeline in char* format which uses shared memory src element to receive this stream and publish it over RTSP stream.

Note: You will need to use the parse element (h264parse, h265parse etc) respective to the encoding format after receiving the stream from shared memory. Also set do_timestamp=false for audio streams.

```
std::string rtsp_launch_str = " shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/stream.socket do_timestamp=true ! h264parse ! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! rtph264pay name=pay0";

// Start RTSP server
loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();
g_object_set (server, "service", port, NULL);

mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);

// Set the constructed char* as launch str
factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, rtsp_launch_str.c_str());
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared (factory, TRUE);
gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory (mounts, "/test", factory);

g_object_unref (mounts);

gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);

g_print ("stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:%s/test\n", port);
g_main_loop_run (loop);
```

This very rough code to create RTSP server, refer this code for more details
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c